# CSS3 Columns children with margin issue w// Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://dev.metertech.co.uk/technologies/patents-and-licensing

On the page above you can see that the second column is pushed down a little from the top.

On a page resize the issue corrects itself.

All other pages, even those with the same number of `<p>` tags for the `.content` render the columns correctly.

I have no idea how I might get it to align properly. Any ideas?

Here are the styles I think you may find relevant.

```
.page .content {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
}
.content p {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

p {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

body {
  font-size: 15.5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

Comment: access to that link is restricted with password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I do not have an explanation for that issue - have you tried using `display: inline-block` for the paragraphs? Applying that seems to fix the issue with chrome.

```
.content p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I thought of that a couple of seconds after you did :) this seems to do the trick. Thank you.